# Port exhaustion

Tags: port, address-space-exhaustion

What does Port exhaustion mean ?
and as QA tester?
how to test it and what are the expected results ?

When I reviewed what the developer wrote :
As a developer I want to update the application to use the new 'serviceClient' Nuget instead of using statements for NetTCP Services.
AC :
ServiceClient Nuget imported into the application
Using statements for NetTCP services replaced with dependency Injection for ServiceClient

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I understand what your dev is saying. They don't want to use the built-in libraries for their project, and are asking to use a different library that they download from NuGet, and use Dependency Injection to integrate it into the application with minimal work.

Personally, unless you are actually experiencing Port Exhaustion (a situation where the host OS no longer has any appropriate ports to give to your application), it sounds like they just like one library better than the other, and have come up with a ramshackle excuse to justify it, but if you are, you would test the software by ensuring that the number of ports opened does not exceed what the system has to offer, and the number does not seem to be going up at an alarming rate.

you can get the number of TCP\UDP ports open at a time using the netstat command, but we'd need to know more about your situation (what OS is this running on, do you have shell access, etc) to give you better advice.